# TypeError when installing jupyter in windows10 OS

Tags: python, typeerror, jupyter

**When I installing Jupyter notebook in my Windows10 OS, but I catched TypeError, and I don't have Anaconda, I just install it via pip in my cmd window, the description following,**

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 666, in _prepare_file
    check_dist_requires_python(dist)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\packaging.py", line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
    feed_parser.feed(metadata)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 175, in feed
    self._input.push(data)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 103, in push
    self._partial.write(data)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'NoneType'
```

There were no solution in Google, who can help me please?

Comment: This is my first question in StackOverFlow , and my English is just-so-so,I hope I have represented my mind slightly.

Comment: Please edit your question with what you typed _before_ getting the error. The context is crucial to understand. Do not worry about your english.

Comment: What version of pip are you using?